# Android studio beta v0.8.14 Install on ubuntu does not include sdk

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-studio

I installed android studio on ubuntu by downloading it directly from http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html#download...According to the site:
"This installation includes:
Android Studio Beta
All the Android SDK Tools to design, test, and debug your app
A version of the Android platform to compile your app
A version of the Android system image to run your app in the emulator"

However there is no sdk included in the package. I also then tried installing android studio using udtc, and the same thing happened. If anybody has installed android-studio beta v0.8.14, successfully your help would be greatly appreciated.